# Aspose.Email assembly to check a mail server ListMessages method fails

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, mail-server, aspose

I am using **Aspose.Email** assembly to check a mail server for any received mails in the inbox. But the **emailClient.ListMessages(emailClient.MailboxInfo.InboxUri)** method in the code below returns the following error,

### Error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
```

### Code:

```
System.Net.NetworkCredential credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domainname");

Aspose.Email.Exchange.ExchangeClient emailClient = new Aspose.Email.Exchange.ExchangeClient("MailserverUri", credential);

Aspose.Email.Exchange.ExchangeMessageInfoCollection messageInfoCollection = emailClient.ListMessages(emailClient.MailboxInfo.InboxUri);
```

### stack trace:

```
 at Aspose.Email.Exchange.ExchangeClient.GetMailboxInfo(String mailbox)
 at Aspose.Email.Exchange.ExchangeClient.GetMailboxInfo()
 at Aspose.Email.Exchange.ExchangeClient.get_MailboxInfo()
 at ACS.PMO.MainForm.ProcessAction() in D:\Projects\MainForm.cs:line 54
 at ACS.PMO.ClientService.MCPClient.ExecuteProcess()
```

### **EDIT**

```
Aspose.Email.Exchange.ExchangeClient emailClient = new Aspose.Email.Exchange.ExchangeClient("MailserverUri", credential);
```

The **MailserverUri** i targeted was Exchange web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it corrected.....

ExchangeWebServiceClient should be used in case of Exchange webservice. Use this class instead of ExchangeClient.The server url is also different in case of EWS.The code i used to overcome the error is as follows,

```
 ExchangeWebServiceClient client = new ExchangeWebServiceClient("https://exchange-server-host/ews/Exchange.asmx", "username", "password", "domain");
```

For further details do check the link below,

http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/301094/405-method-not-allowed-while-connecting-to-exchange-web-service.aspx